# I want to navigate on a url after login in Angular js (4.4.6)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Loginservice } from './services/login.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector    : 'app-login',
    templateUrl : 'user-login.html',
    styleUrls   : ['styles/login-style.css']

})
export class UserLogin{

    public userDetail:any[];
    public islogin:boolean;
    public routers : Router;
    constructor(private service:Loginservice){

    }
    loginform = new FormGroup({
        username    : new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
        password    : new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
    });

    get username(){
        return this.loginform.get('username');
    }
    get password(){
        return this.loginform.get('password');
    }

    getStyle(){
        return {
            'font-size': '11px',
            'text-align': 'center'
        };
    }

    authLogin(loginObj){

        let username = loginObj.value.username;
        let password = loginObj.value.password;
        let postdata = {'username':username, 'password':password};
        //console.log(postdata);
        this.service.validateUser(postdata)
                    .subscribe(
                       response => {
                           this.islogin= response.json().status=='1'?true:false;
                           //alert(this.islogin);
                           //console.log(response);
                           this.routers.navigate(['/register']);
                       },
                       error =>{
                           alert(error+"asdsadsa");
                       }

                    );

    }
}
```

this is the code of my component. when i login then i want to go to another component having a common header and footer. but it does not go to any component and giving error "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined". and one more thing i want to know that how to add common header and footer file in each component except login/registration.

Comment: That means `this.routers` is undefined. That's the only helpful thing we can say based on what you posted in the question. Of course we could imagine 36 reasons why it could be undefined, but it would be much easier if you just posted your code. The bug is in there. Not in angular.

Comment: Please post your component code as this might be caused by a typo, or not importing a dependency. Both of these possibilities can not be confirmed with the code you have provided.

Comment: ok now i have posted my component code. now please help me...

Comment: yes...i found the first solution ...i just put the routers property in the constructor and it is working fine.Now second issue is yet remain that how to set common header and footer for all component except login/registration

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to achieve it is create separate header and footer components, as I did, below:

[image]

The code inside header and footer can represent whatever you want:

```
<div class="footer">
<i class="material-icons">&#xE90C;</i>{{copyright}}
</div>
```

and

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'footer',
    templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
})

export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
    copyright: string;
    constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

   this.copyright = 'My Copyright';
    return;

  }

}
```

Similarly you can create header component.
Once done, all you need to do is to use the selector tags, wherever you want to include it, generally in case of different HTML files.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="content" class="flex-col">
            <div>
                <header></header>
            </div>
            <div class="content fluid flex-col">
                <My-App></My-App>
            </div>
            <div>
                <footer></footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you rahul ...but i want to make it dynamic. like if i navigate to any url after login/registration then header and footer should be same

Comment: In any case, you will need to have a home component, which will hold these header, and footer, and is redirected to after you log in. Replacing <My-App> with <router-outlet>  in this home component and displaying the remaining Urls as child of the home will help you achieve it. Do you need help with the child url routing in such case ?